# Copying the phone number into the clipboard in the Google Voice application

Tags: google-voice

In the application [Google Voice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice&hl=en) is there any way to copy the Google phone number into the clipboard without having to type anything?

I use a Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III with a rooted Android 4.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't copy anything from the list view, but if you tap the message to open it, then tap the "compose" button...

[image]

...then you can select the phone number from the bar at the top the normal way (by long-pressing):

[image]